# compare month part of date using entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I want to get data of current month using entity framework, database have a field named Date but i need to get data on the basis of current month of particular person.

```
[WebMethod]
public string getAttendanceofUserofMonthbyId(int id)
{
    string Date;
    List<AttendenceGetSet> lst = new List<AttendenceGetSet>();
    List<AttendenceGetSet> lst2 = new List<AttendenceGetSet>();

    AttendenceGetSet gs = new AttendenceGetSet();

    //Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Replace("-", "/");
    string month = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
    usersGetSet usergetset = new usersGetSet();

    using (SoubhagyatechEntities dbcontext = new SoubhagyatechEntities())
    {

        lst = dbcontext.tblempAttendences.Where(i => i.Date == month && i.userId == id).Select(i => new AttendenceGetSet
        {

            userAddress = i.userAddress,
            userLatitude = i.userLatitude,
            userLongitude = i.userLongitude,
            Date = i.Date,
            userId = i.userId,
            Time = i.Time,
            empAttendenceId = i.empAttendenceId,

            username = dbcontext.tblusers.Where(j => j.userId == id && j.userStatus == true).Select(j => j.userFullName).FirstOrDefault()



        }).ToList();

    }

    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string jsons = jss.Serialize(lst);
    return jsons;
}
```

Comment: list return empty

Comment: Can you please try this line `dbcontext.tblempAttendences.Where(i => i.Date.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && i.userId == id)` ? I am assuming that your date is stored as DateTime in database.

Comment: error :'string' does not contain a definition for 'Month' and no extension method 'Month' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: There are  many things which can go wrong. You shouldn't store Date as string in database, ideally it should be a datetime. Can you write a SQL query and check if the database really has data with your where conditions.

Comment: database have data in string format "dd/MM/YYYY" having field name "Date"

Comment: It's always better to do a range query: `>= mindate && < maxDate`.

Comment: You can parse string (i.Date) to DateTime and then try. Where(i => DateTime.ParseExact(i.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month == DateTime.Now.Month && i.userId == id)

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the code below?

```
var mindate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
var maxdate = first.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
dbcontext.tblempAttendences.Where(i => i.Date >=mindate && i.Date<=maxdate && i.userId == id)
```